# Why does this wmic command not work in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

I have a set of programs that i need to install, uninstall etc through batch files. 
So my batch file containst this line

```
wmic product where name="ABCcorp Tool" get version
```

Works fine, except for this tool

```
wmic product where name="XYZ® Tool" get version
```

It just prints

```
No Instance(s) Available.
```

Works perfectly if I run the same through the command line directly(administrator run)

Suspecting the Registered sign to be the culprit I changed it to

```
wmic product where "Name like 'XYZ%'" get version
```

Same problem: Runs directly on Command line but not through batch file.
What should I do here?

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `chcp` to get displayed which code page is used on __your__ machine for __your__ account depending on __your__ Windows region and language settings. You can find on Wikipedia the various code pages, for example [OEM 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) (U.S., Canada), [OEM 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) (Western European countries), [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_1252) (in GUI apps in North America, Western Europe). Your problem was caused by not using right code page on writing the batch code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a workaround than a solution.
I figured out how to get the "Name like" correctly. Basically, it should be

```
wmic product where "Name like 'XYZ%%'" get version
```

inside a Batch file becuase % is a special character that needs to be escaped.

So my problem is solved, but in case someone knows how to do it with the "®" sign, it may be useful for others.